# Spring Boot on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and logging to a file

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been looking to find an easy way to view debug statements on Beanstalk as I develop.  I thought I could simply log to a file on Beanstalk.

In my application.properties file I set

```
logging.file.path=/var/log
```

And that did not produce any results even on my local machine.  I am not sure if it's a permission issue or what, but locally I set the path to my home directory and then I saw the file, spring.log, appear.

With Beanstalk I tried /var/log, var/log/tomcat, /home/webapp/, ./, ~, and various other values.  Nothing worked.

I even tried what was suggested here with no luck:  https://medium.com/vividcode/logging-practice-for-elastic-beanstalk-java-apps-308ed7c4d63f

If logging to file is not a good idea, what are the alternatives?  I have Googled a lot about this issue and all answers are not very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is permission issues. Your app runs under `webapp` user, while `/var/log` is own by root. Thus you can't write to it.

The proper way of adding your log files to be recognized by EB is through config files.

Specifically, assuming Amazon Linux 2, you can create `.ebextensions/mylogfiles.config` with the content of:

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/myapplogs.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       /var/app/current/log/*.log
```

Obviously, `/var/app/current/log/*.log` would point to location where your app stores its log files. `/var/app/current` is the home folder of your app.

Comment: Hi.  I tried /home/webapp as well and that didn't work.  Should it?  In any case I am not able to add the .ebextensions folder to the root of my spring boot war package as is needed.  I Googled around for it and there are many different solutions, but they all seem to be outdated.  None worked for me.  Do you have any knowledge on that? I am using Maven

Comment: @ChrisLam You can store the logs in `/home/webapp`, but you need to tell EB to look for logs there, using the config files. For now just, do it manually. SSH into the EB instance, create the log config files, and verify if it works. Then you can worry how to automate the process.

Comment: When I asked about /home/webapp I was referring to when I set logging.file.path to there...without using ebextensions.  Anyways I used ebextensions as you suggested and I found out the easiest way to have it in the root of the WAR with Maven is to put .ebextensions in /src/main/webapp folder (not the src/main/resources folder as many claimed).

Comment: @ChrisLam Thanks for letting me know. Did it  work?

Comment: So I just finished uploading the new WAR.  No errors but I did not see  a /var/app/current/log/ created.  I am logging in my app org.slf4j.Logger.  Right now I am doing some INFO level logging.

Do I need to add some settings in my application.properties file?

Comment: @ChrisLam I'm not familiar with `org.slf4j.Logger`. The EB logs should be available in the  EB console for download. On the left, there is menu with logs. There you can choose to download full logs as zip. If correctly configured, your app's logs should be included there.

Comment: OK.  So I was confused before.  ebextensions is just telling EB to look in `/var/app/current/log/*.log` for log files and to include those in the log section of the EB console.  It doesn't actually take care of writing logs for me.  So I just set the path of `logging.file.path=/var/app/current/log` and voila..I am getting logs.  Thank you so much!